# Ubuntu 15.10 wifi connection but often fails to get internet access

Tags: ubuntu, internet, ubuntu-15.10

I am running ubuntu 15.10 and my Lenovo yoga 2 pro laptop often fails to connect to the Internet. This happens randomly and could pass several hours before it is able to connect again. The laptop stays connected to the router via WiFi, but no Internet access. Other laptops and smartphones connect with no problems to the net.

This is the output of ifconfig

```
Lenovo-Yoga-2-Pro:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Loopback locale
           indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
           indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0
           Byte RX:87572 (87.5 KB)  Byte TX:87572 (87.5 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 7c:7a:91:a3:fd:63
           indirizzo inet:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255 
Maschera:255.255.255.0
           indirizzo inet6: fe80::7e7a:91ff:fea3:fd63/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000
           Byte RX:14096 (14.0 KB)  Byte TX:53883 (53.8 KB)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you confirm what steps you have taken so far to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Actually I am quite confused, because of the fact that the connection sometimes works and others not. However, I have tried reinstalling the WiFi drivers and switching ipv6 settings to ignore. No positive results after these.